# Estrange \n at the end of the file name when checking my md5 files

Tags: linux, command-line, hashsum

For a reason a do not understand when checking my md5 files, it fails because the name of the file have a \n at the end but the file name doesn't have this character. These are old files I have on my computer. If I do the same operation with md5 generated more recently, I don't get that error. Example:

```
ls
R1_001.fastq.gz
R1_001.fastq.gz.md5

md5sum -c R1_001.fastq.gz.md5
md5sum: R1_001.fastq.gz\n: No such file or directory
R1_001.fastq.gz\n: FAILED open or read
md5sum: WARNING: 1 listed file could not be read
```

Can you see the `\n`. However, the same operation with another more recently created md5 file doesn't return this error and checking is ok.

I have check if there is a new line character at the end of this file with `find . -name \*$'\n'\*` and there is NOT any file with a \n in its file name. So, what is going on?

I have also tried `ls -Q` and `ls -b` but I can't see the \n in any file.

I have also change the file name twice, first R1_001.fastq.gz to R1_001.fastq.ggz and then R1_001.fastq.ggz to R1_001.fastq.gz. And the same error with the same error I got

```
cat -A R1_001.fastq.gz.md5
5bfa62079341df049fb4c5eb9d0c6fcc R1_001.fastq.gz\n
```

Comment: If you run `cat -A R1_001.fastq.gz.md5`, what does it show? (Please *edit your question* to add this information.)

Comment: ohhh!!, the \n is in the md5. I thought it is in the file name. First time working with md5. If I remove the new line character everything should work fine.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the `.md5` file contains a spurious character or two. Is it an actual new line character, or is it actually two characters: a backslash and a letter `n`? If the latter, then whatever program was used to create the `.md5` file seems to have had a small bug in it. If the former, I'll be puzzled: is your system perhaps configured for Windows-style `\r\n` line endings rather than for Unix-style plain `\n`?